# Build latest version of FFMPEG with libx264 Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, libx264

I was able to Build FFMPEG with libx264 Android successfully and was working well before 2 months.

I uses [halfninja](https://github.com/halfninja/android-ffmpeg-x264) for building.

Today I take latest source of ffmpeg and libX264 from here.

```
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264.git

git clone git://git.videolan.org/ffmpeg.git
```

And try to rebuild whole project. But now it throws following errors.

```
 ffmpeg.c:2406: error: undefined reference to 'hwaccels'
 ffmpeg.c:3390: error: undefined reference to 'qp_hist'
 ffmpeg.c:3390: error: undefined reference to 'do_hex_dump'
 ffmpeg.c:3390: error: undefined reference to 'do_pkt_dump'
 ffmpeg.c:576: error: undefined reference to 'do_benchmark_all'
 ffmpeg.c:657: error: undefined reference to 'audio_sync_method'
 ffmpeg.c:1222: error: undefined reference to 'vstats_filename'
 ffmpeg.c:972: error: undefined reference to 'frame_drop_threshold'
 ffmpeg.c:1181: error: undefined reference to 'debug_ts'
 ffmpeg.c:2742: error: undefined reference to 'copy_tb'
 ffmpeg.c:2846: error: undefined reference to 'audio_volume'
 ffmpeg.c:2862: error: undefined reference to 'init_simple_filtergraph'
 ffmpeg.c:2863: error: undefined reference to 'configure_filtergraph'
 ffmpeg.c:2923: error: undefined reference to 'video_sync_method'
 ffmpeg.c:2538: error: undefined reference to 'frame_bits_per_raw_sample'
 ffmpeg.c:3258: error: undefined reference to 'sdp_filename'
 ffmpeg.c:2087: error: undefined reference to 'ist_in_filtergraph'
 ffmpeg.c:4069: error: undefined reference to 'ffmpeg_parse_options'
 ffmpeg.c:4074: error: undefined reference to 'show_usage'
 ffmpeg.c:3303: error: undefined reference to 'options'
 ffmpeg.c:3303: error: undefined reference to 'stdin_interaction'
 ffmpeg.c:2553: error: undefined reference to 'exit_on_error'
 ffmpeg.c:2553: error: undefined reference to 'do_pkt_dump'
 ffmpeg.c:2553: error: undefined reference to 'do_hex_dump'
 ffmpeg.c:3727: error: undefined reference to 'copy_ts'
 ffmpeg.c:3727: error: undefined reference to 'dts_delta_threshold'
 ffmpeg.c:268: error: undefined reference to 'dts_error_threshold'
 ffmpeg.c:3976: error: undefined reference to 'print_stats'
 ffmpeg.c:1694: error: undefined reference to 'do_benchmark'
 ffmpeg.c:1694: error: undefined reference to 'max_error_rate'
```

Please help me out to resolve this.

Please look at my script.

**build_android.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# build_android.sh
# Copyright (c) 2012 Jacek Marchwicki
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

export NDK=/home/tasol/DEVELOPMENT/IJOOMER_DEVELOPMENT/NDK/android-ndk-r10d

if [ "$NDK" = "" ]; then
    echo NDK variable not set, exiting
    echo "Use: export NDK=/your/path/to/android-ndk"
    exit 1
fi

OS=`uname -s | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
function build_x264
{
    PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/$PLATFORM_VERSION/arch-$ARCH/
    export PATH=${PATH}:$PREBUILT/bin/
    CROSS_COMPILE=$PREBUILT/bin/$EABIARCH-
    CFLAGS=$OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS
#CFLAGS=" -I$ARM_INC -fpic -DANDROID -fpic -mthumb-interwork -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__  -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -mthumb -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -DANDROID  -Wa,--noexecstack -MMD -MP "
    export CPPFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
    export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
    export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
    export CXX="${CROSS_COMPILE}g++ --sysroot=$PLATFORM"
    export AS="${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc --sysroot=$PLATFORM"
    export CC="${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc --sysroot=$PLATFORM"
    export NM="${CROSS_COMPILE}nm"
    export STRIP="${CROSS_COMPILE}strip"
    export RANLIB="${CROSS_COMPILE}ranlib"
    export AR="${CROSS_COMPILE}ar"
    #export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog"

    cd x264
    ./configure --disable-asm --prefix=$(pwd)/$PREFIX --host=$ARCH-linux --enable-static $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG || exit 1

    make clean || exit 1
    make -j4 install || exit 1
    cd ..
}

function build_ffmpeg
{
    PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/$PLATFORM_VERSION/arch-$ARCH/
    CC=$PREBUILT/bin/$EABIARCH-gcc
    CROSS_PREFIX=$PREBUILT/bin/$EABIARCH-
    PKG_CONFIG=${CROSS_PREFIX}pkg-config
    if [ ! -f $PKG_CONFIG ];
    then
        cat > $PKG_CONFIG << EOF
#!/bin/bash
pkg-config \$*
EOF
        chmod u+x $PKG_CONFIG
    fi
    NM=$PREBUILT/bin/$EABIARCH-nm
    cd ffmpeg
    export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=$(pwd)/$PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig/
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(pwd)/$PREFIX/lib/pkgconfig/
    ./configure --target-os=linux \
        --prefix=$PREFIX \
        --enable-cross-compile \
        --extra-libs="-lgcc" \
        --arch=$ARCH \
        --cc=$CC \
        --cross-prefix=$CROSS_PREFIX \
        --nm=$NM \
        --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
        --extra-cflags=" -O3 -fpic -DANDROID -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums  -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS " \
        --disable-shared \
        --disable-stripping \
        --enable-static \
        --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
        --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib  -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog -L$PREFIX/lib" \
        --extra-cflags="-I$PREFIX/include" \
            --enable-gpl \
        --enable-encoder=libx264 \
        --enable-libx264 \
        --enable-parser=mjpeg \
        --enable-demuxer=image2 \
        --enable-hwaccel=h264_vaapi \
        --enable-hwaccel=h264_vaapi \
        --enable-hwaccel=h264_dxva2 \
        --enable-hwaccel=mpeg4_vaapi \
        --enable-demuxer=mov \
        --enable-demuxer=h264 \
        --enable-demuxer=mpegvideo \
        --enable-demuxer=h263 \
        --enable-demuxer=mpegps \
        --enable-demuxer=mjpeg \
        --enable-demuxer=rtsp \
        --enable-demuxer=rtp \
        --enable-demuxer=hls \
        --enable-demuxer=matroska \
        --enable-muxer=rtsp \
        --enable-muxer=mp4 \
        --enable-muxer=mov \
        --enable-muxer=mjpeg \
        --enable-muxer=matroska \
        --enable-protocol=crypto \
        --enable-protocol=jni \
        --enable-protocol=file \
        --disable-network \
            --enable-filter=buffer \
        --enable-filter=buffersink \
        --enable-filter=scale \
        --enable-protocol=rtp \
        --enable-protocol=tcp \
        --enable-protocol=udp \
        --enable-protocol=applehttp \
        --enable-protocol=hls \
        --enable-protocol=http \
        --enable-decoder=xsub \
        --enable-decoder=jacosub \
        --enable-decoder=dvdsub \
        --enable-decoder=dvbsub \
        --enable-decoder=subviewer \
        --enable-decoder=rawvideo \
        --enable-encoder=rawvideo \
        --enable-decoder=mjpeg \
        --enable-encoder=mjpeg \
        --enable-decoder=h263 \
        --enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
        --enable-encoder=mpeg4 \
        --enable-decoder=h264 \
        --enable-encoder=h264 \
        --enable-decoder=aac \
        --enable-encoder=aac \
        --enable-parser=h264 \
        --enable-encoder=mp2 \
        --enable-decoder=mp2 \
        --enable-encoder=libvo_amrwbenc \
        --enable-decoder=amrwb \
        --enable-muxer=mp2 \
        --enable-bsfs \
        --enable-decoders \
        --enable-encoders \
        --enable-parsers \
        --enable-hwaccels \
        --enable-muxers \
        --enable-avformat \
        --enable-avcodec \
        --disable-demuxer=v4l \
        --disable-demuxer=v4l2 \
        --disable-indev=v4l \
        --disable-indev=v4l2 \
        --disable-ffplay \
        --disable-ffmpeg \
        --disable-ffplay \
        --disable-ffprobe \
        --disable-ffserver \
        --enable-nonfree \
        --enable-version3 \
        --enable-memalign-hack \
        --disable-asm \
        $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG \
        || exit 1
    make clean || exit 1
    make -j4 install || exit 1

    cd ..
}

function build_one {
    cd ffmpeg
    cd ..
}

#arm v5
EABIARCH=arm-linux-androideabi
ARCH=arm
CPU=armv5
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-marm -march=$CPU"
PREFIX=../ffmpeg-build/armeabi
OUT_LIBRARY=$PREFIX/libffmpeg.so
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
SONAME=libffmpeg.so
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/$OS-x86_64
#PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/$OS-x86
PLATFORM_VERSION=android-5
build_x264
build_ffmpeg
build_one


#arm v7vfpv3
#EABIARCH=arm-linux-androideabi
#ARCH=arm
#CPU=armv7-a
#OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -marm -march=$CPU "
#PREFIX=../ffmpeg-build/armeabi-v7a
#OUT_LIBRARY=$PREFIX/libffmpeg.so
#ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=
#SONAME=libffmpeg.so
#PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/$OS-x86_64
#PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/$OS-x86
#PLATFORM_VERSION=android-5
#build_x264
#build_ffmpeg
#build_one

#arm v7 + neon (neon also include vfpv3-32)
EABIARCH=arm-linux-androideabi
ARCH=arm
CPU=armv7-a
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -marm -march=$CPU -mtune=cortex-a8 -mthumb -D__thumb__ "
PREFIX=../ffmpeg-build/armeabi-v7a
#PREFIX=../ffmpeg-build/armeabi-v7a-neon
OUT_LIBRARY=../ffmpeg-build/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg-neon.so
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=--enable-neon
SONAME=libffmpeg-neon.so
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/$OS-x86_64
#PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/$OS-x86
PLATFORM_VERSION=android-9
build_x264
build_ffmpeg
build_one

#x86
EABIARCH=i686-linux-android
ARCH=x86
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-m32"
PREFIX=../ffmpeg-build/x86
OUT_LIBRARY=$PREFIX/libffmpeg.so
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=--disable-asm
SONAME=libffmpeg.so
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/x86-4.8/prebuilt/$OS-x86_64
#PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/$OS-x86
PLATFORM_VERSION=android-9
build_x264
build_ffmpeg
build_one

#mips
EABIARCH=mipsel-linux-android
ARCH=mips
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-EL -march=mips32 -mips32 -mhard-float"
PREFIX=../ffmpeg-build/mips
OUT_LIBRARY=$PREFIX/libffmpeg.so
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG=""
SONAME=libffmpeg.so
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.8/prebuilt/$OS-x86_64
#PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.6/prebuilt/$OS-x86
PLATFORM_VERSION=android-9
build_x264
build_ffmpeg
build_one
```

**build_all.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# build_all.sh

export NDK=/home/tasol/DEVELOPMENT/IJOOMER_DEVELOPMENT/NDK/android-ndk-r10d
sudo ./build_android.sh
$NDK/ndk-build

echo "Done Dona Done!!!"
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE  := videokit
# These need to be in the right order
FFMPEG_LIBS := $(addprefix ffmpeg-build/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/, \
 libavdevice.a \
 libavformat.a \
 libavfilter.a \
 libavcodec.a \
 libswscale.a \
 libavutil.a \
 libswresample.a \
 libpostproc.a )
# ffmpeg uses its own deprecated functions liberally, so turn off that annoying noise
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -g -Iffmpeg -Ivideokit -Wno-deprecated-declarations 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lz $(FFMPEG_LIBS) ffmpeg-build/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/libx264.a
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := videokit/uk_co_halfninja_videokit_Videokit.c videokit/ffmpeg.c videokit/cmdutils.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE  := ffmpeg
FFMPEG_LIBS := $(addprefix ffmpeg-build/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/, \
 libavdevice.a \
 libavformat.a \
 libavfilter.a \
 libavcodec.a \
 libswscale.a \
 libavutil.a \
 libswresample.a \
 libpostproc.a )
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -g -Iffmpeg -Ivideokit -Wno-deprecated-declarations 
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -lz $(FFMPEG_LIBS) ffmpeg-build/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/lib/libx264.a
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ffmpeg/ffmpeg.c ffmpeg/cmdutils.c
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_ABI := armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86,mips
APP_PLATFORM := android-10
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

**UPDATE**

**Finally Got success**

Comment: Specify the reason for down vote. If you don't understand the question that your fault.

Comment: I upvoted to balanced it out. I did a very similar question year ago, ffmpeg is pretty complex stuff. Good luck.

Comment: halfninja says it's unsupported now. Did you check the forks?

Comment: yes it said that he will not going to give more support any more. Same thing is working with me with older version of FFMPEG. But there is lots of changes in latest version of FFMPEG. So it is not working.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I am also facing a similar issue. Could you please tell, how did you solve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia WHat ARCH & CPU do you specify for arm64-v8a architectures ?